# Android Bluetooth Piconet Broadcast data

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcast

I have some questions regarding Piconet in Android:

1. Is it possible with the Bluetooth Android API to broadcast data that was sent by one slave to all (master and slaves) in the Piconet? If it is possible, how does it work? Does it go to the master first and then to all slaves, or does the slave directly contact other slaves?
2. Can one device connect to two or more different Piconets?
3. If the master is down, can it delegate automatically to other slaves?

FYI, I'm using both master and slave on an Android mobile phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible with bluetooth android API to broadcast data that was sent by one slave and the data will be received to all (master and slave) in the piconet? If it is possible, how does it works? It goes to the master first and then gives to all slave, or slave directly one by one contact another slave?

in a piconet you have one master and unto 7 active slaves, Bluetooth broadcast works form Master to all slaves - In android there are no APIs for applications to use the broadcast feature.
Slaves can directly talk to only the master. It is a star topology Master talking to slaves and slaves to Master.

> Can one device connect to two or more different piconet?

Yes - You can me Master in one piconet and slave in other piconet/s
Or Slave/s in different piconet/s

> If the master is down, can it delegates automatically to other slave?

No

Comment: thank you for you answer!

I still confuse, you said in the first answer bluetooth broadcast works from master to all slaves. but in android it does not have any broadcast feature? So it is not possible in android for slave to send data to master and master distribute (broadcast) to other slave?


How many master for one bluetooth device can make? Or how many connection (include it becomes both slave and master) for one bluetooth device can make? (in one piconet it only can connect up to 7 active slaves)

Comment: please do vote up and accept the answer if it helps. With android public APIs it is not possible to do what you have stated - One piconet is One master connected to unto 7 active slaves, there are no limits devices being part of multiple piconets , it is just limited by the resources in the system

Comment: Sorry im noob here, i cannot vote because i don't have enough reputation. How to accept answer? 

Ohh i see.. so i cannot progress for what i start T_T.. Maybe this is OOT, do you know what mobile API can do bluetooth broadcasting like that? Thanks!

Comment: you should see a small tick when you move the mouse below the vote button - clicking that accepts the answer. Don't know of other mobile Apis that can do broadcast