# J2ME bluetooth piconet broadcast data

Tags: java-me, bluetooth, broadcasting

Refer to my question in [Android Bluetooth Piconet Broadcast data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891386/android-bluetooth-piconet-broadcast-data?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I know that android question regarding to piconet is already answered. Now i've done some research regarding to bluetooth broadcasting piconet with J2ME.

I want to ask some question regarding Piconet in J2ME:

1. Is it possible with bluetooth J2ME API to broadcast data that was sent by one slave and the data will be received to all (master and slave) in the piconet? If it is possible, how does it works? It goes to the master first and then gives to all slave, or slave directly one by one contact another slave?
2. Where can i find the resource regarding to bluetooth broadcasting with J2ME? (i still have problem when i googled it)

FYI, im using both master and slave using J2ME mobile phone not computer.

Thank you :D. Really appreciate your help :D

Comment: Got any new info about bluetooth broadcasting?